# Was partial replacement were removed in Turbolinks 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-5

I am wondering if Turbolinks 5 has partial replacement as in 3rd version.
Also where is the 3rd version, is it Turbolinks-classic? At the rubygems site I can find only 2.5 and 5th version listed. In turbolinks-classic documentation I see partial replacement documentation which says for versions (3+). So I lost where is the Turbolinks 3, or is it just now called Turbolinks 5? Sorry if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turbolinks jumped from v2 to v5. They were working towards v3 but put a halt on it. In v5 "Turbolinks replaces the current `<body>` element outright and merges the contents of the `<head>` element," - so there is no partial replacement.

This interview with DHH helps to understand his thinking behind Turbolinks 5 and the jump from v2 - https://youtu.be/ktZLpjCanvg?t=48m18s

Comment: I'm learning Turbolinks and I was trying to use partial replacement with no result at all. What's your advice? Should I just drop it? Or is it something worth to learn? I just wanted to load content asynchronously.

Comment: Maybe this is something you could use - "data-turbolinks-permanent": https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads

For background see also: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/wiki/Turbolinks-5-FAQ#why-did-you-remove-partial-replacement